# Flask "no such option --debug"

Tags: flask

This happens when you try to run flask app using

```
flask run --debug
```

Tried:

```
flask run --debug
```

Expecting:

```
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 272-345-882
```

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution to this is to change the order:

```
flask --debug run
```

and if you want to add other flags, you can!

```
flask --debug run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Answer (score 2):

I was following the Quickstart guide of flask documentation and faced this error "No such option: --debug"

This solution worked for me.

`flask --debug run`

Putting --debug before run.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was an old version of Flask. Running `pip install --upgrade flask` fixed it.